# How to transfer a file from one server to another every time this file has changed automatically

Tags: amazon-s3, file-transfer, filezilla

I have a **Windows 2003** server with Filezilla installed on it. There are some folders with files that need to be updated to **AWS S3** every time any file is changed, but it needs to be **automatic**.
Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use FileZilla for that.

You could create a Windows scheduled task to run `aws s3 sync` on a recurring schedule. The file wouldn't copy to S3 immediately, but it would we automatic.